# A special case of the integer Hodge conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, open-problems

Let $X$ be a projective complex manifold of dimension $n$. 
Are torsion cohomology classes in $H^{2n-2}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ algebraic?
(We may assume, without loss of generality, that $n=3$, because of the Lefschetz
hyperplane theorem.) I know that torsion classes (of even codimension) aren't always algebraic; 
the first counterexamples were found by Atiyah and Hirzebruch in 1960s. But I do not know any 
counterexample in this codimension.

Note that by Poincare duality 
$H^{2n-2}(X,\mathbb{Z})\cong H_2(X)$, so the equivalent question is whether
torsion classes in $H_2(X)$ are generated by algebraic curves in $X$. 
This looks like a "dual" to the well known fact that torsion classes in 
$H^{2}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ are generated by divisors (it is a torsion part of the Neron-Severi group).

Comment: Here is something worth considering.  Let $Y$ and $Z$ be complex, projective manifolds each of which has $p$-torsion in $H_1$, e.g., $Y$ and $Z$ are both Enriques surfaces so $H_1=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  Now let $X$ be the product $Y\times Z$.  By Kunneth's theorem, there is torsion in $H_2(X,\mathbb{Z})$.  What algebraic cycle gives rise to this torsion?

Comment: It makes sense. This trick does not work for divisors, because $H^1$ has no torsion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [2013 paper](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~totaro/papers/public_html/integral.pdf) of Totaro says that it is an open question. But the integral Hodge conjecture is known to fail for dimension 1, just not via torsion.